How to we calculate the raditaion pressure on a refraction surface?
Consider a situation there is a glass sphere, light enter in it.
The raditaion pressure on reflective surface is easier to determine by the change of light momentum.
However, on the inner surface there is also a refraction.
How to determine the light momentum in glass?
How to we calculate the raditaion pressure for refraction?
How to determine the direction of the force due to the raditaion pressure from the refraction surface?
By the law of energy conservation, if there is a pressure on a compressible surface there must be some energy exchange, how does photon transfer energy during refraction process?
I found out a paper, it shows a similar situation but it did not show how to calculate the force.   https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.24.156

For example in this paper how to dertermine the direction and magnitude of $F_D^i$
Should we use minkovsiki momentum? should we use group velocity or phrase velocity?
While the glass particle is accelerated, if the light color change (frequency) after reflection or refraction?

i found out a paper shows a similar situation but it did not show how to calculate the force.   https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.24.156

The people and organizations that make solar sails work very hard to make the reflective surfaces be specularly reflective (what you see when you look in a mirror). There are multiple types of reflection, of which specular reflection is but one type. Other types of reflection include diffuse reflection (what you see when you look at sunlight shining on a lawn or a tree), retroreflection (what you see when your car's (or more importantly, a police car's) headlights hit a modern license plate), internal reflection (what you see when you see a rainbow), and others.
In general, we only slightly calculate the effects of reflection other than specular reflection regarding radiation pressure because the materials are designed to avoid those other types of reflection. However, because solar sails are thin they will be slightly transparent and/or slightly absorptive (these are modeled), and because the materials used won't be perfect mirrors, there will be some diffuse reflection (also modeled).
As far is I know, the rather small effects of refraction are not modeled. We don't send glass spheres into space.

When light enters glass, it does not lose energy. It does not gain energy when it leaves the other side.
When glass deflects light, its momentum changes direction but the magnitude does not change.
So you can figure out the force from the change in momentum per unit time. How much light enters the glass in a second? How much is the total momentum of that light? What was the change in momentum?
There are three changes in momentum to consider. Some light is reflected. Some transmitted. Some absorbed.
For the absorbed light, all of the momentum is transferred to the glass.

If the energy density us $u=({\bf E\cdot D} + {\bf B\cdot H})/2$, doesn't the magnitude change? And is momentum density $u/v=un/c$?

If a pulse of light enters glass, it slows down and therefore gets shorter. The energy density goes up. But the total energy does not.

I do need to dd a caveat to what I said. If light exerts a force on glass and accelerates it, the glass gains velocity. This causes a Doppler shift. The reflected beam has a lower frequency and less energy. This is the kinetic energy gained by the glass. I was assuming the glass was massive enough that this is negligible.

I posted a calc using 4 vectors, so radar momenta $k_{\mu} \rightarrow k'{\mu} $ bouncing off a moving target with $p{\mu} = (E, \vec p)=mu_{\mu}$...if you insist the 4-momentum transfer is orthogonal to the. 4-velocity (so the target stays 'on-shell'), you get the relativistic doppler shifts, with recoil as $m\rightarrow 0$. Could work for this problem.
